# Meaning of *:* in lsof output

Tags: unix, lsof

On Solaris (or Unix), running `lsof` gives me a bunch of lines like this:

```
java    25375 foo 8161u  IPv4 0xfffffeb1f6f523c0        0t0        TCP *:* (IDLE)
```

But the `*:*` puzzles me - I was expecting to see something like

```
hostname1:port1->ipaddress:port2 (IDLE)
```

What does the `*:*` mean?

Answer (score 2):

I will quote this from [here](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/netstat-network-analysis-and-troubleshooting-explained/):

> If the Foreign Address is `*:*` (and, with TCP sockets, the state is
>   LISTEN), a socket is usually waiting for some remote host to send the
>   first data. Typical examples: sshd (waits for somebody to open an ssh
>   connection), apache (waits for somebody to request a web page), cupsd
>   (waits for somebody to send a print job), and dhclient (waits for the
>   DHCP server to send, for example, a lease renewal).

Comment: Ok. So the example in the question corresponds to an idle tcp connection maintained by java.exe. What does anything:anything mean in this context? Put another way; under what circumstances is a tcp connection maintained with anything:anything ? It seems like a tcp connection should be associated with a specific host

Comment: No, it's not `anything:anything`. `IPv4 INADDR_ANY` and `IPv6 IN6_IS_ADDR_UNSPECIFIED` addresses, and `zero port numbers` are represented by an asterisk ('*').

Comment: @Petr what might cause an idle `*:*` tcp socket?

Comment: Yes, it's probably socket. A newly created TCP socket has no remote or local address and is not fully specified (no ports associated, ...).

Comment: You mean a "half-open" tcp connection?

Comment: Not even half-open. There is actually no connection (yet) here. It is an unbound socket and Mondkin reply is irrelevant, that's not the foreign address which is `*:*` but the local one. @PetrDuchek you should make your comment a reply.

Comment: Why would a large number of unbound IDLE sockets be created? I have an issue with the process file descriptor limit being blown by around 7k unbound IDLE TCP connections being created. Put another way, what could result in the creation of an unbound socket? Naively, such a socket seems to be pointless.